# Объединение таблиц БД посредством LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity

В базе данных хранятся следующие таблицы:

### Books

BookID | BookName | Author | Genre | BookYear | Price | Count | Publishing |

### Users

UserID | FullName | Login | Password | Adress | Telephone |

### Sellings

SellingID | UserID | BookID | SaleCount | SaleDate |

При помощи Sellings нужно объединить данные из всех троих таблиц в следующею:

### Report

SellingID | BookID | BookName | Price | SaleCount | FullName | SaleDate

Помогите, пожалуйста, объединить данные в таблицу Report при помощи LINQ запроса(если есть способы по лучше, буду рад почитать). Также нужно чтобы можно было просматривать данные за определенный период(SaleDate). Выходная таблица должна быть DataTable.

К каждой из таблиц обращаюсь так:

```
this.bookstoreDataDataSet.Books;
this.bookstoreDataDataSet.Users;
this.bookstoreDataDataSet.Sellings;
```

В качестве БД использую MS Access

Comment: Вам нужно делать либо .Include либо написать новый класс и написать Select. Рапишите ваши классы Books, Users, Seilings и Report в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Эм. Это у вас Entity Framework, верно? Нет в тегах и нет явного указания.

Comment: @AK - вангую, что это типизированный датасет.

Comment: Ага, всё же EF. А классы? Если хочется разобраться самостоятельно: [Include и загрузка связанных данных](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level3/3_4.php) и [Select и проекции](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/4.2.php) В общем-то ничего сложного. Ответом не оформляю, т.к. нет описания классов и кода соответственно тоже не могу дать.

Comment: я может, что то не понимаю, но это чет какой-то ... . У вас получается есть таблицы справочники и таблица с данными о продажах. Вам необходимо, чтобы был сформирован отчет содержащий данные из всех таблиц- как я понимаю тут надо запрос написать и все. т.к. связывание таблиц бд в приложении, ну это нехорошо явно

Comment: @NMD Ну да, нужен запрос, видимо linq не особо хорошо пока понимает. Хотите сами ответить? )

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, но нет))) просто предложил вариант решения

Comment: @NMD Окей, как сделать запрос к БД чтобы мне вернули таблицу, которую потом я смогу вставить к примеру в DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, Вам нужен такой запрос

```
IEnumerable<Report> report = (from s in sellings
                              join b in books on s.BookID equals b.BookID
                              join u in user on s.UserID equals u.UserID
                              select new Report
                              {
                                    BookID = b.BookID,
                                    BookName = b.BookName,
                                    FullName = u.FullName,
                                    Price = b.Price,
                                    SaleCount = s.SaleCount,
                                    SaleDate = s.SaleDate,
                                    SellingID = s.SellingID
                              });
```